# Why across() and summarise_at() don't recognize the column namse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Below I'm simply trying to summarise the mean of 3 columns (`Direct cost`, `ICU days`, `Length of stay (Hours)`) in `AWD_wide` data.frame.

I wonder why they both say they don't recognize the columns?

**Note:** Please assume I can't use `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

AWD <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/aw.csv')

AWD_long <- AWD %>%
  gather(key = "var", value = "Outcome", -Patient) %>%
 separate(var, into = c("Outcome_Measure", "Treatment"), sep = "-") %>%
    select(Patient, Treatment, Outcome_Measure, Outcome)


AWD_wide <- 
  AWD_long %>%
  spread(Outcome_Measure, Outcome)

# Option 1: -----------------------------------
AWD_wide %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(`Direct cost`, `ICU days`, `Length of stay (Hours)`), mean) 

# Option 2: -----------------------------------
AWD_wide %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>% 
  summarise(across(3:5,~mean))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv`.  Otherwise, with the default `check.names = TRUE`, it will change the spaces etc. with `.` and thus not matching the column names while we specify those in the `vars`

```
AWD <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/aw.csv',
         check.names = FALSE)



names(AWD_wide) <- trimws(names(AWD_wide))
AWD_wide %>%
   group_by(Treatment) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(c("Direct cost", "ICU days", "Length of stay (Hours)")), mean)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Treatment        `Direct cost` `ICU days` `Length of stay (Hours)`
#  <chr>                    <dbl>      <dbl>                    <dbl>
#1 " Ativan"               11903.       1.38                      195
#2 " Phenobarbital"         4928.       0                          87
```

---

Or using `across`

```
AWD_wide %>%
 group_by(Treatment) %>% 
 summarise(across(where(is.numeric),mean), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Treatment        `Direct cost` `ICU days` `Length of stay (Hours)`
#  <chr>                    <dbl>      <dbl>                    <dbl>
#1 " Ativan"               11903.       1.38                      195
#2 " Phenobarbital"         4928.       0                          87
```

---

Based on the edit, if we are not using `check.names = FALSE`

```
AWD_wide %>%
    group_by(Treatment) %>%
    summarise(across(matches('Direct.cost|ICU.days|Length.of.stay'), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian then you can use the updated version as well or change the names in `vars` by matching the column names

Comment: @rnorouzian in your new edit, there are multiple `Direct.cost` columns in 'AWD_wide'

Comment: @rnorouzian the code `%>% separate(var, into = c("Outcome_Measure", "Treatment"), sep = "-")` i.e. `sep = "-"` wouldn't work there because there are no `-` in the column names